# Python (pandas) - reset index with count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame:

```
  HH     PERSON SPOT    WEIGHT
  1002141   aa   1      1332.25
  1011831   ab   1      2083.31
  1031726   aa   1      2589.09
  1042819   aa   1      4736.28
  1043006   aa   1      1588.39
  1043006   aa   1      1588.39
  1060911   aa   1      1113.97
  1001665   aa   2      3202.09
  1001762   aa   2      2048.54
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a count column all the occurrences that repeat themselves, 
in the example above lines 5 and 6 are the same, so I want want the output to be:

```
  HH     PERSON SPOT    WEIGHT    COUNT    
  1002141   aa   1      1332.25     1
  1011831   ab   1      2083.31     1
  1031726   aa   1      2589.09     1
  1042819   aa   1      4736.28     1
  1043006   aa   1      1588.39     2
  1060911   aa   1      1113.97     1
  1001665   aa   2      3202.09     1
  1001762   aa   2      2048.54     1
```

What I did is:

```
count_table=df.groupby(['HH','PERSON','SPOT ID']).agg(['count']).reset_index()
```

It works, but the indexes get all messed up - and it sorts it by the HH column instead of by the original index.

Any ideas how I can reset the table indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` for this to add a count column which is just the group size in this case:

```
In [164]:
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['HH','PERSON','SPOT'])['WEIGHT'].transform('size')
df

Out[164]:
        HH PERSON  SPOT   WEIGHT  Count
0  1002141     aa     1  1332.25      1
1  1011831     ab     1  2083.31      1
2  1031726     aa     1  2589.09      1
3  1042819     aa     1  4736.28      1
4  1043006     aa     1  1588.39      2
5  1043006     aa     1  1588.39      2
6  1060911     aa     1  1113.97      1
7  1001665     aa     2  3202.09      1
8  1001762     aa     2  2048.54      1
```